# Is there a way to implement this using transform instead of for_each? If yes, is it actually better to do so?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, unordered-map

Given a string s, how can I use transform to create an unordered_map that contains the number of times each character was encountered? Is it worth the bother?

My initial thought was to use transform, but I wasn't sure how to implement the "increment value if exists, else add" part. I ended up using for_each instead.

Using for_each:

```
unordered_map<char, int> charMap;
for_each(begin(s), end(s), [&charMap](char c){charMap[c]++;});
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like this, but for map instead of multimap:

```
unordered_multimap<char, int> charMap2;
transform(begin(s), end(s), inserter(charMap2, begin(charMap2)), [&](char c){
        return make_pair(c, 1);
        });
```

UPDATE:
See @patatahooligan's comment for why, although hackable enough to make it work, transform (intended for 1-to-1 transformations) might not be best suited here. 
See Maxim's (accepted) answer for more suitable strategies.

Comment: i'd use a plain loop. why do you think this needs improvement?

Comment: I don't specifically, but given that I wanted to take a range, apply a transformation and stick it into another container, I figured I should be able to use transform to do it. I was curious if that was possible.

Comment: i see, I didnt mean to say "wtf dont do it", but it was just curiosity as well ;)

Comment: @varjun This code does a `groupby` with `count` aggregation for each group. C++ standard library doesn't provide `groupby`. `unordered_map` does `groupby` for you but you still need to manually apply the aggregation function.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `std::transform` is meant for 1-1 transformations, ie when each element of the output corresponds to one element of the input. This is not true here. While it is possible you could hack an output iterator that makes it work, it doesn't mean that `std::transform` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for that, @patatahooligan. This definitely influences the way I'll think of transform going forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get it any better in terms of compile time, execution speed and readability than a plain range-for loop:

```
unordered_map<char, int> charMap;
for(char c : s) 
    ++charMap[c];
```

You can make it even faster if you replace `unordered_map<char, int>` with `int[256]`:

```
int charMap[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {}; // Zero-initialized.
for(unsigned char c : s) 
    ++charMap[c];
```

And if you do need `unordered_map<char, int>` you can build it from that `int[256]` array:

```
unordered_map<char, int> charMap2;
for(auto const& count : charMap)
    if(count)
        charMap2[&count - charMap] = count;
```

I guess, using `int charMap[256]` only pays off when the string `s` is somewhat long.

Comment: Nifty approach :)